# Sistema de instalação/cópia de arquivo

Tags: c#, dicionário, instalador

Como utilizar os itens

```
SortedDictionary
File.WriteAllBytes
```

para começar ou concluir um processo de instalação de arquivos e pastas para o computador.

Ex:

Lista de arquivos:

```
void AlocarArquivos(){
var arquivo_e_pasta = new SortedDictionary<string, byte[]>();
arquivo_e_pasta.Add(@"\bin32\dedicated.exe", Properties.Resources.bin32_dedicated);
arquivos_e_pastas.Add(@"\sdk\player.df", Properties.Resources.PLAYER_DF_BTS);
}
```

E depois ir de um em um aplicando isso:

```
var enum0 = arquivos_e_pastas.GetEnumerator();
while(enum0.MoveNext()){
    File.WriteAllBytes(enum0.Current.Key, enum0.Current.Value);
}
```

Mas só que tendo o progresso da instalação aplicando `Thread.Sleep` sem travar o aplicativo.

Comment: Eu duvido que precise de um `SortedDictionary` para isto. Você deveria dar preferência para o `foreach`. O problema da pergunta é que ela está muito solta. Não tem um contexto.

Comment: Nathan, por favor, prefira [formatar seus posts em Markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Se usar `<pre><code>`, o código não renderiza a marcação de linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

que tal criar uma nova Thread para esta operação?

```
 new System.Threading.Thread((enum) => {
//Converta a enum para o objeto de sua preferencia...
var Enum = (var)enum;
while(Enum.MoveNext()){
    File.WriteAllBytes(Enum.Current.Key, Enum.Current.Value);
}}).Start(enum0);
```

Nesse algoritmo será iniciada uma tarefa em uma thread secundária, ao executar esse comando o processo será feito e a Thread principal (seu programa) irá continuar em execução... infelizmente o problema disso é que o programa pode iniciar antes dessa thread executar o algoritmo... (Nesse caso recomendo fazer um algoritmo de espera na classe Main, antes de iniciar a form principal...)